# Getting bad padding exception while decrypting using AES CBC PCKS7 padding

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

So I have some code in Java for encrypting and decrypting objects and I've been trying to do the same in C# so my server and client can decrypt and encrypt messages. At the moment the last piece of the puzzle I need to fix is my C# decryption. When attempting to decrypt, I usually get a bad padding exception of sorts. However, Java is using PCKS5 padding and C# is using PCKS7 padding which if I understand correctly are virtually indistinguishable.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class EncryptedBytes {

    private final byte[] data;
    private final byte[] params;
    private final String paramAlgorithm;

}

    /**
     * Encrypt object with password
     *
     * @param data   Object to be encrypted
     * @param secret Password to use for encryption
     * @return Encrypted version of object
     */
    public static EncryptedBytes encrypt(String data, SecretKey secret) throws InvalidKeyException {

        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);

            // properly encode the complete ciphertext
            //logEncrypt(password, object);

            byte[] encodedData = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
            byte[] params = cipher.getParameters().getEncoded();
            String paramAlgorithm = cipher.getParameters().getAlgorithm();

            return new EncryptedBytes(encodedData, params, paramAlgorithm);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | IllegalBlockSizeException | NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt data with secret
     *
     * @param encryptedBytes Object to be decrypted
     * @param secret         Password to use for decryption
     * @return Decrypted version of object
     */
    public static String decrypt(EncryptedBytes encryptedBytes, @NonNull SecretKey secret) throws InvalidKeyException {
        try {

            // get parameter object for password-based encryption
            AlgorithmParameters algParams = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(encryptedBytes.getParamAlgorithm()); // getParamAlgorithm usually just returns "AES"


            if (algParams == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("EncryptedBytes.Parameters are not valid");

            // initialize with parameter encoding from above
            algParams.init(encryptedBytes.getParams());

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, algParams);

            return new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes.getData()), CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | IOException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now in C# I have a very close implementation to the Java code above.

```cs
    public class EncryptedBytes
    {
        [NotNull]
        public List<sbyte> data { get; }

        [NotNull]
        [JsonProperty("params", Required = Required.Always)]
        [JsonPropertyName("params")]
        public List<sbyte> keyParams { get;  }

        [NotNull]
        public string paramAlgorithm { get; }

        public EncryptedBytes(IEnumerable<sbyte> data, [JsonProperty(propertyName: "params")] IEnumerable<sbyte> keyParams, string paramAlgorithm)
        {
            this.data = data.ToList();
            this.keyParams = keyParams.ToList();
            this.paramAlgorithm = paramAlgorithm;
        }
    }

       public static EncryptedBytes encrypt(AesCryptoServiceProvider aesCryptoServiceProvider, string plainText,
            Encoding encoding)
        {
            if (encoding == null) encoding = StaticHandler.encoding; // UTF_8

            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (aesCryptoServiceProvider.Key == null || aesCryptoServiceProvider.Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (aesCryptoServiceProvider.IV == null || aesCryptoServiceProvider.IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");


            ICryptoTransform transform = aesCryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor();

            var encodedText = encoding.GetBytes(plainText);
            var encryptedText =
                transform.TransformFinalBlock(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length).Select(Convert.ToSByte);

            var derOctetString = new DerOctetString(aesCryptoServiceProvider.IV);


            return new EncryptedBytes(encryptedText, derOctetString.GetEncoded().Select(Convert.ToSByte), "AES");
        }

        public static string decrypt([NotNull] EncryptedBytes encryptedBytes, AesCryptoServiceProvider aesCryptoServiceProvider, Encoding? encoding)
        {
            if (encoding == null) encoding = StaticHandler.encoding;

            var cipherText = encryptedBytes.data.Select(arg => (byte) arg).ToArray();

            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (aesCryptoServiceProvider.Key == null || aesCryptoServiceProvider.Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (aesCryptoServiceProvider.IV == null || aesCryptoServiceProvider.IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.

            aesCryptoServiceProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            var transform = aesCryptoServiceProvider.CreateDecryptor();
            string plaintext;

            var keyParams = encryptedBytes.keyParams.Select(b => (byte) b).ToArray();

            var octetString = (DerOctetString) Asn1Object.FromByteArray(keyParams);

            aesCryptoServiceProvider.IV = octetString.GetOctets();
            aesCryptoServiceProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            plaintext = encoding.GetString(transform.TransformFinalBlock(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length));

            return plaintext;

        }
```

The main code in question is this:

```cs
            var transform = aesCryptoServiceProvider.CreateDecryptor();
            string plaintext;

            var keyParams = encryptedBytes.keyParams.Select(b => (byte) b).ToArray();

            var octetString = (DerOctetString) Asn1Object.FromByteArray(keyParams);

            aesCryptoServiceProvider.IV = octetString.GetOctets();
            aesCryptoServiceProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            plaintext = encoding.GetString(transform.TransformFinalBlock(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length));
```

For testing purposes, you may use this value as an example of data that is parsed (EncryptedBytes class converted to JSON)

```
{"data":[-91,-105,-48,-75,18,-64,-12,-122,56,76,17,101,54,65,53,-10],"params":[4,16,81,-32,-95,-80,-81,100,-81,58,49,-36,35,21,-115,-110,111,-2],"paramAlgorithm":"AES"}
```

This should just return empty brackets as plaintext.
Expected result:

```
{}
```

You may use this key: (both values are the same key, written differently)

```
Byte array: 15,215,133,73,75,92,34,113,122,135,36,209,240,159,54,165,30,23,86,73,166,7,166,192,209,145,68,167,19,205,105,55
Base64: D9eFSUtcInF6hyTR8J82pR4XVkmmB6bA0ZFEpxPNaTc=
```

Comment: Your Java code uses the Java defaults.  Your C# code uses the C# defaults.  If those defaults do not match (and they probably don't) then decryption will fail.  Go through your code and explicitly set *all* defaults for both encryption and decryption.  One of the common ones is the string-to-byte conversion.  Is the default UTF-8 or UTF-16?  What byte order is used?

Comment: You claim that you use CBC mode which requires an IV. But on Java you neither create an IvParameterSpec nor specify it in Cipher.init(..).

Comment: @rossum I specified UTF-8 on both actually. They're both AES 256 CBC PCKS5/7 padding.

Comment: @Robert I believe the IV is generated when the key is generated (java class found at [my github](https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat/blob/master/java/core/src/main/java/com/github/fernthedev/lightchat/core/encryption/util/EncryptionUtil.java)) The IV is actually provided from key parameters in Java as far as I know from looking at the decompiled sources (cipher.getParameters().getEncoded() and algParams.init(encryptedBytes.getParams()))

Comment: Lots of strange stuff here, like signed bytes in C# and and ASN1 classes for some reason make their appearance as well in C#. As is always the case a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would make all the difference and eliminate the 20 questions game.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any `StaticHandler` class in Java. Agree with President James. We are left guessing.

Comment: Right. Would my [github repo](https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat) serve as a MCVE or would a smaller application (such as providing a key and sample data to decrypt) work as a MCVE?

Comment: No offline resources are no MCVE. A key and sample data would work I suppose.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've edited my question, removed referecnes to classes such as `StaticHandler` and added a key with data to decrypt. I hope that will suffice as a MCVE though feel free to ask any more information from my code :)

Comment: There are just too many variables to work with here. In Java I see no mention of JSON or DER, while those are present in C#. I have got the strong feeling that you're trying to get two pieces of code to interoperate by just trying things, rather than trying to rewrite the Java code in C#, which is probably what is required in this case. To debug this, make sure that the key, IV and data are identical for both Java and C# decryption by printing out the values in hexadecimals. If they are not, *something other than the cipher is wrong* (and that's likely the case).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you for your advice, it seems it is the logical way to go about this. Though I was hoping it was just a simple two lines of code missing of sorts that could be applied. Guess it's back to the drawing board to do this.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Ok so I've logged the data, key and parameters and such and oddly enough they are all identical (though I used Base64 convert to make it easier to read rather than check a list of bytes if that changes anything) So something else is at play here. Here are the logs: https://gist.github.com/Fernthedev/bb78e8b7825ece59302df940f4c4504f

Comment: Interesting, because I don't even see in the code above where you are setting the key. I must admit that this is one of the weirdest ways of distributing the IV and such I've seen so far.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yeah... I must admit, I'm no encryption expert. In fact, I'm mostly gluing it together with the basic knowledge of "don't expose the key, and the key converts plain text to giberish and giberish to plain text". The key is generated [here](https://github.com/Fernthedev/light-chat/blob/5b69ef26232b822d5d54835a040837b68474ffdd/csharp/core/encryption/EncryptionUtil.cs#L215-L230)

Comment: That's OK, but you may think about splitting out the encryption / decryption code so you can test things separately. Currently I see JSON, base 64, encryption and such all intermixed. Which means that debugging and testing is going to be somewhat of a nasty experience (and not just for you, this is near impossible to solve for others - including me - as well).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yeah, I thought so. Guess solving this issue is going to be a headache for me as much as for others. I can't really figure out why C# is doing this. Might be because BouncyCastle is .NET Framework and I'm using .NET Core but at this point the clues point to no where. I was able to solve this in Dart and Dart uses PCKS7 instead of PCKS5 so I'm not sure why it won't work here. The debugger shows the exception is thrown when padding is less than 0 or greater than some number I can't recall.

Comment: There is [no difference between PKCS#5 and PKCS#7](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/1172) compatible padding, so that's not it.